# Guice - Binding an instance created by assisted injection factory

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3, assisted-inject

Let's say  that there's class A that's constructor looks something like that:

```
public A(@Assited long id, @Assisten String name, ServiceA serviceA, ServiceB serviceB)
```

And there's AFactory:

```
public interface AFactory{

    A create(long id, String name);
}
```

So to create an instance of A I obviously need to do something like that:

```
injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
AFactory af = injector.getInstance(AFactory .class);
A a = AFactory.create(100, "mike");
```

BUT,
Let's say I have other classes: Class B,  Class C and Class D that has a member with type A, for example(with field injection but can be ctor also):

```
    public class B{
       @Inject
       A a;
    }
```

And I want that the **same instance** of A will be injected to those classes.
But still have the option to inject another instance of A to other classes (let's say Class E and F).

What is the correct way of doing that?
I just can't think of a clean way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure your module to use Providers (I'm using [@Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) methods below, but you can use full Provider classes or instances if you'd like), and mark the consistent A as [@Singleton](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes). If you want two bindings of A (consistent and inconsistent), at least one of them should be marked with a binding annotation; I'm using `@Named` here out of convenience, but you can use any binding annotation as listed [in the docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations).

```
public class AModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    // Install your AFactory module. Here, injections for AFactory should succeed.
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(AFactory.class));
  }

  /**
   * Provides a singleton @Named("consistent") A.
   * Inject @Named("consistent") A into B, C, and D; Guice will cache the instance.
   */
  @Provides @Singleton @Named("consistent")
      A provideConsistentA(AFactory factory) {
    return factory.create(100, "mike");
  }

  /**
   * Provides an unscoped A.
   * Inject A without an annotation into E and F; each instance will be separate.
   */
  @Provides @Singleton A provideUnscopedA(AFactory factory) {
    return factory.create(200, "jeff");
  }
}
```

Comment: So if I will just have a field in class E as follows:
@Inject @Named("consistent")

Comment: `@Inject @Named("consistent") A fieldName`, but yes. And the key "consistent" can be anything, as long as you're consistent about it. :)