# Guice: Inject singleton with constructor with own parameters?

Tags: java, singleton, guice

I had a question about injecting custom parameters ([Guice: Inject class with constructor with own parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537240/guice-inject-class-with-constructor-with-own-parameters/66538160#66538160)), however the solution does not work for singletons. Does anyone know how this works for singletons? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a good answer on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40517556/6099243

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me.